# Jackson throws JSONMappingException cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable (through reference chain ***)

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson

I have a JSON string. I am converting it using jackson's ObjectMapper.
This is the JSON string.

```
{
  "stat": "OK",
  "response": {
    "result": "auth",
    "status_msg": "Account is active",
    "devices": [
      {
        "device": "DPFZRS9FB0D46QFTM891",
        "type": "phone",
        "number": "XXX-XXX-0100",
        "name": "",
        "capabilities": [
            "auto",
            "push",
            "sms",
            "phone",
            "mobile_otp"
        ]
      },
      {
        "device": "DHEKH0JJIYC1LX3AZWO4",
        "type": "token",
        "name": "0"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have defined an object like:

```
public class MyClass{
  private String stat;
  private Response response;
  //getters and setters
}
```

Then I defined response as:

```
public class Response{
  private String result;
  private String statusMsg;
  private SortedSet<Device> devices = new TreeSet<Device>();
  //getters and setters
}
```

Finally, Device is defined as:

```
public class Device implements Comparator<device>{
  private String device;
  private String number;
  // etc variables
  @Override
public int compareTo(Device o) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return o.getNumber().compareTo(this.number);
}
```

Finally, when I use the mapper:

```
mapper.readValue(json.getBytes(), MyClass.class);
```

I get this exception:
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Device cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable (through reference chain: Response["response"]->Response["devices"])

What should I do to implement a sortedset device array in this case?

Comment: Does it really say `implements Comparator<device>`? That should not compile. Device should be upper-case and it should be Comparable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement `java.lang.Comparable` interface. Or provide comparator to `TreeSet` constructor.

```
class Device implements Comparable<Device> {

    private String device;
    private String number;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Device o) {
        return o.number.compareTo(this.number);
    }
}
```

Or provide `Comparator` instance to `TreeSet`:

```
TreeSet<Device> devices = new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<Device>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Device o1, Device o2) {
        return o1.getNumber().compareTo(o2.getNumber());
    }
});
```

Since `Java 8`:

```
TreeSet<Device> devices = new TreeSet<>((d1, d2) -> d1.getNumber().compareTo(d2.getNumber()));
```

Or even a little better:

```
TreeSet<Device> devices = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(Device::getNumber));
```